# Why when update dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary   with `{k:[list]}` where `k` value of `i` 
for the first iteration, it works but  `{3:[20,20,20]}` but when increase and added to the dictionary 
`{3:[20,20,20,20],4:[20,20,20,20]}` instead of  `{3:[20,20,20],4:[20,20,20,20]}` and goin
`{3:[20,20,20,20,20],4:[20,20,20,20,20],5:[20,20,20,20,20]}` instead of
`{3:[20,20,20],4:[20,20,20,20],5:[20,20,20,20,20]}`

```
d0 = 20
tempsq=[]
c=[]
anon={}
minm=0
for i in range(3,len(sq)):
    if i<2*kd:
        # print(i)
        cost=compute_I(sq[0:i])
        c.append(cost)
        #from hear
        tempsq.clear()
        for j in range(0,i):
             tempsq.append(d0)
        if not anon:
            anon = {i: tempsq}
            print(anon)
        else:
            anon.update({i:tempsq})
            print(anon)


print(anon)
```

Comment: but i don't want copy list i want to add for each i new list [20,20,20] in dictionaey .the list  it can be any list i proposal this value as example

Comment: `{i:[d0]*i for i in range(3,len(sq))}` gives `{3: [20, 20, 20], 4: [20, 20, 20, 20], 5: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]}` when `len(sq) == 6`

Comment: it's work thank you

Comment: You question is very unclear and your example cannot be ran because sq is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to create a list:

```
{3: [20,20,20], 4:[20,20,20,20],...}
```

You can achieve that running the following:

```
value = 20
min_iteration = 3
max_iteration = 5

{i : [value]*i for i in range(min_iteration, max_iteration+1)}
```

Which yields:

```
{3: [20, 20, 20], 4: [20, 20, 20, 20], 5: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]}
```